# Hide and show a div not working, the element changes its property When I use console.log() but not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `ASP.NetCore 2.0` got a view and I'm trying to show and hide an element when the user uses a `toggle` button but I really don't know what's happening

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="row" id="ToggleClasificarIVA">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-check has-success">
                                <label class="control-label">Clasificar Impuesto al valor agregado</label>
                                <div class="switch">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="ClasificarIvaToggle" ><span class="lever"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="row" id="CodigoActividadDropdown" style="display:none">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group has-success">
                                <label class="control-label">Codigo de Actividad</label>
                                <select class="form-control custom-select">
                                    <option value="0">---Seleccione---</option>
                                    <option value="1">Cedula Fisica</option>
                                    <option value="2">Cedula Juridica</option>
                                    <option value="3">Dimex</option>
                                    <option value="4">Nite</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**And my JS:**

```
$('#ClasificarIvaToggle').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').css("display", "block");
        alert("Checekado")
        console.log(document.getElementById("CodigoActividadDropdown"))
    }
    else {
        $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').css("display", "none");
        alert("UnChecekado")
        console.log(document.getElementById("CodigoActividadDropdown"))

    }
});
```

**I've tryed to use :**

```
$('#ClasificarIvaToggle').click(function () {
if (this.checked) {
    $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').css("display", "block");
    alert("Checekado")
}
else {
    $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').css("display", "none");
    alert("UnChecekado")

}
});
```

**Also:**

```
$('#ClasificarIvaToggle').change(function () {
if (this.checked) {
    $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').fadeIn('slow');
}
else {
    $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

});

**Even with js only:**

```
document.getElementById("ClasificarIvaToggle").onclick = function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("CodigoActividadDropdown").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("CodigoActividadDropdown").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

When I log the element with `console.log(getElementByID(""))`, I can see the element changing the display property but it's not showing in my document.

Comment: Was it working before and it is not working now? Or is it just not working and you need some debugging?

Comment: It never worked :(, need some debugging I've been on this issue for two hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#ClasificarIvaToggle'). change(function () {
         if (this.checked) {
             $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').hide();

           }
           else {
                 $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').show();
           }
           });
      });
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I appreciate it a lot, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I used exactly what you provided and it works on JSfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/fnchz375/

```
$('#ClasificarIvaToggle').click(function () {
if (this.checked) {
    $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').css("display", "block");
    alert("Checekado")
    console.log(document.getElementById("CodigoActividadDropdown"))
}
else {
    $('#CodigoActividadDropdown').css("display", "none");
    alert("UnChecekado")
    console.log(document.getElementById("CodigoActividadDropdown"))

}
```

});

Could you provide any logs/error from console you are getting. Also, feel free to try example on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this once, this should not be failed :)

```
jQuery('body').on('change','#ClasificarIvaToggle',function(){

    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        jQuery(this).parents("#ToggleClasificarIVA").find("#CodigoActividadDropdown").show();
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(this).parents("#ToggleClasificarIVA").find("#CodigoActividadDropdown").hide();
    }
});
```